# Delphi serial port Comport data

Tags: delphi, port, tcomport

I have an application that listens on a serial port.  It uses `TComPort` to connect to the serial port, and a timer to listen.  Basically, all we're doing is listening for data, specifically barcodes.  However, we seem to have a problem.  The data "comes across" in the form `#0#0#0#0....` when a barcode is scanned.

The code is as follows:

```
if Comport2.Active then
begin
  sStr := Comport2.ReadAnsiString;
  if Length(sStr) <> 0 then
  begin
    MatCodeEdit.Text := '';
    MatCodeEdit.Text := sStr;
  end;
end;
```

The serial port is connected with the following parameters:

```
Comport2.DataBits := db8;
Comport2.Parity := paNone;
Comport2.StopBits := sb1;
```

No errors occur on connection.  The above code has, actually, succeeded in reading the contents of the serial port transmission.  But, currently seems only to receive the `#0#0#0...` string.

Does anyone have any ideas about this?

Comment: Is `#0#0#0...` what you are actually seeing in `MatCodeEdit` at runtime, or are you seeing it in the debugger instead? It makes sense that the debugger might display that, but you certainly should not be seeing it in `MatCodeEdit`. Where is the call to `ReadAnsiString()` actually being made from exactly? In a timer event? Why not in one of the `TComPort.OnRx...` events? And how is the barcode scanner *supposed* to be sending data to you, in what format exactly? How are barcodes delimited? Which barcode scanner are you using exactly? Some scanners have alternative ways to send data to apps.

Comment: If you can add more detail to answer Remy's questions, please [edit] the question to include it.  Otherwise, there really isn't enough information here to provide any useful help.

Comment: One more question  - you have not shown baudrate parameter. Is it set correctly?

Comment: The baud rate is 9600.  The contents of the data string is simply the barcode from the scanner.  There are no additional characters like STX or ETX.  Or any other delimiters of any sort.

Comment: For questions regarding serial communication, in addition to a **proper problem description**, **specify the protocol** you are implementing, **specify equipment** (manufacturer, model), **show complete code** you have tried for both sending and receiving, version info of the **communication library** and it's **setup** you are using. If any of these are missing, your question is incomplete. Additionally, specifically re. your question, what is the role of the timer? What exactly is the code in the `OnTimer` event?

Comment: Have you tried any terminal program?

Comment: Yes I have tried a terminal program.  It works fine and returns the correct values. Which makes me suspect the code.  But that same code has, in fact, worked fine previously.  The code in the OnTimer event is in the example I provided.  The make and model is a Magellan 8400.